# Discontinue sales on appstore and still offer updates

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an app on AppStore that I am about to pull. But I would like to offer updates to existing users. Is that possibe?

Comment: Not to have them go to the AppStore to get the update.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Why would you want to discontinue an app you are still updating?

Comment: We are moving from a paid app to a free app with subscription and the ones that allready bought the app shall keep it the way it is. But I don't want any others to buy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once it's deleted from the App Store, if they don't have a backup of that app locally, they won't even be able to install it back, so forget about providing updates to an app that isn't in the App Store anymore.

Interesting read:

http://lifehacker.com/5867673/what-do-i-do-when-apple-removes-an-app-i-bought-from-the-app-store